# How to set version number for SDK in iOS/Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk, version, xcode7-beta3

I'm writing an **iOS SDK** using **Objective-C** programming language. I would like to know if there is a field in Xcode where i can set version number for SDK

Is there a way in objective-C to **set version and build** number the way we do it for iOS apps (EX: Version: 2.5.1 Build: 2.5.1.12) ?

Also need a way to detect this version number so i can expose an API something like

```
- (NSString *)getSDKVersion {
    NSDictionary *infoDictionary = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
    NSString *majorVersion = [infoDictionary objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
    NSString *minorVersion = [infoDictionary objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SDK Version %@ (%@)", majorVersion, minorVersion];
}

-(NSString*)getSDKBuildVersion;
```

Which returns the SDK version and build number.

Using:
Xcode - 7.0 (Beta 3 version)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your SDK has a Info.plist file you can put your version in `CFBundleShortVersionString` key and your build number in `CFBundleVersion`. To retrieve them : `[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"]` or `[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"]`

Comment: @ryancrunchi updated the question with the implementation. On executing the above API i'm getting null response.

Comment: You may have to create your own bundle (a SDK's bundle) and access it with `[NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"id"]...`. From apple's doc : `This method is typically used by frameworks and plug-ins to locate their own bundle at runtime `

Answer (score 3):

You can set version and build number clicking in the **Project**(left side) -> **General** tab(right side) -> **Identity** section. You will find the fields: *Bundle Identifier*, *Version* and *Build*.

For get the values programmatically:

```
NSDictionary *infoDictionary = [[NSBundle mainBundle]infoDictionary];

NSString *version = [infoDictionary objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
NSString *build = [infoDictionary objectForKey:kCFBundleVersionKey];
```

Comment: Thank you but when we create SDK project General tab will not be there. And i have edited the info.Plist file still i'm unable to get the version number using the 'CFBundleShortVersionString" key.

Comment: @AnkitJain Can you find solution to set custom sdk version?

Comment: To make this work in my framework, I had to replace `[NSBundle mainBundle]` with `[NSBundle bundleForClass:self.class]`.